# Merge two binary search trees together in Prolog

Tags: prolog, binary-search-tree

I am working on a SWI-Prolog program where I merge two binary search trees together, but I'm getting the wrong output. BST `T2` is the result of inserting every node from BST `T1` into BST `T`.

```
 merge(T,T1,T2).
```

The code that I have right now:

```
 add_BST(T , T1 , T2).
 add_BST(t(L , T1 , R ) , t(L , T2 , R), t(t(L , ROOT , RIGHT ) , T1 , NT)) :- 
     T1 < T2 , add_BST(T2 , T1  , NT).
 add_BST(t( L , T1 , R) , t(L , T2 , R), t(NT1 , T1 ,t( LEFT , ROOT ,R ))) :- 
     T1 > T2 , add_BST(T2 , T1  ,NT1).
```

The output for this:

```
?- add_BST(t(nil , 1 , nil) , t(nil , 2 , nil) , NT).

true;

NT=t(t(nil,_G1601, _G1602),1,_G1598)
```

I am looking to get a binary search tree in the output and dont know what Im doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have a few cases of not using variables.  For example, in your second rule, what is the variable `ROOT` supposed to be used for?

Comment: The ROOT is meant to store the roof of the tree

Comment: I am guessing that you are getting warnings when you try to compile this code. Don't ignore them: if you figure out why you get the warning, and how to avoid them, you might solve the problem on your own.

Answer (score 1):

*Start small. Start with what you already know:*

```
add_BST( t(nil , 1 , nil) , t(nil , 2 , nil) , NT) :-
```

This is a quite valid piece of code, a head of a predicate which deals with merging `t(nil , 1 , nil)` with `t(nil , 2 , nil)`. What do we know about this situation?

```
    1 < 2,
```

Its result should quite obviously be

```
    NT = t( t(nil , 1 , nil) , 2, nil ).
```

Try it:

```
?- add_BST( t(nil , 1 , nil) , t(nil , 2 , nil) , NT).
```

or,

```
?- A=1, B=2, add_BST( t(nil , A , nil) , t(nil , B , nil) , NT).
```

This one hopefully gives us an idea of re-writing it as

```
add_BST( t(nil , A , nil) , t(nil , B , nil) , NT) :-
    A < B, 
    NT = t( t(nil , A , nil) , B, nil ).
```

You should be able to generalize it further from here, and cover more possible cases (like, `A > B`, etc.).